# Tire.search "index" not returning same results as Index.search

Tags: elasticsearch, tire

Tire.search is not working for me, while using the search function on the Model is.

```
Tire.search "articles" do
  query { string "pizza" }
end
```

returns 0 results.

```
Article.search "pizza"
```

returns the results that I expect. What could be the problem?

Comment: Some verbose output of your mappings would be helpful.